# Create conditional in Model methods

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi guys i wish to create a custom method on my Category Model but i need to create some conditionals with it.

```
table post:
- id;
- category_id
-name...


table Category:
- id
- parent_id
- name
```

Imagin that i have a post, and in this post there is a category called SomeSubcategoryName, i my posts table i have a column called category_id.

When i call the post record i have a relation with the Category Model, but i wish to have in my Category Model a method called masterCategory, where i give the mster category by checking if the parent_id is null or not, in case that the record have a parent_id of null great, i return the record but if is not i need to use the parent_id value and search on the Model category column id for the record and return the result.

Imagine this scenario:

```
$post = Post::find(2);
```

//this call should return the main category and not the subcategory info.

```
$post->masterCategory();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your category model define a relationship on its self:

```
public function masterCategory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(App\Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

Eager load the relationships on your `Post` when you query it:

```
$post = Post::with(['category', 'category.masterCategory'])->firstOrFail($id);
```

Access it like this:

```
$post->category->masterCategory; // will be the mastery category or null
```

Otherwise us:

```
$post->category;
```

Don't over complicate it.

Comment: I think is enought putting: $post = Post::with('category.masterCategory')->firstOrFail($id);
It already breings the category and masterCategory all together

Answer (score 0):

In your Category model you should have something like this

```
public function master()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function isMaster()
{
    if($this->parent_id)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Now you can check that post's category is master or not :

```
if($post->category->isMaster())
    ....
```

The second way is using relations and eloquent

```
$post = Post::with(['category', 'category.master'])->first($id);
```

Comment: the ideia is than using eaguear loading, since i want to prevent in a foreach loop make requests in making the category->isMaster vertification.

Comment: I think is enought putting: $post = Post::with('category.masterCategory')->firstOrFail($id); It already breings the category and masterCategory all together